# Symfony fosuserbundle add Account entity to a person entity

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle, registration

I have a Symfony project with FOSUserBundle, i extended the FormType in my personal Bundle following this guide "http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html"

I created a Person entity with first name, last name, adresse ..., created its FormType like this :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('firstName', TextType::class)
            ->add('lastName', TextType::class)
            ->add('adress', TextType::class)
            ->add('account', AccountType::class) ;
}
```

The Account entity is the user class for FOSUserBundle

Then i generated the CRUD for Person, the newAction() looks like this :

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $person = new Person();
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\PersonType', $person);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $person->getAccount()->setEnabled(1); //i'm doing this because it's not automatic
        $em->persist($person->getAccount());
        $em->persist($person);
        $em->flush($person);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_security_login'); // redirecting to the login page because it's not done automatically
    }
    return $this->render('person/new.html.twig', array(
        'person' => $person,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

The two entitys have a OneToOne relationship, with this code they are both persisted in the data base and i can use the username and password to log in normally

Here is my FOSUerBundle configuration :

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\Account
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
    registration:
        form:
            type: AppBundle\Form\AccountType
```

I want to the user to log in automatically after registration like it happens when using the default FOSUserBundle registration, anyone got an idea how to do so ?

I tried a lot of stuff but no success

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to login from my controller using the $person->getAccount() object:

All i have to do is dispatch the REGISTRATION_COMPLETED event like in the default Controller : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php#L78

Just copied some code to my controller

This will trigger the authentication : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/EventListener/AuthenticationListener.php